# What are the dangers of extreme temperature for an acoustic piano?

Tags: piano, maintenance

I am planning to buy an upright acoustic piano in the future. But before I do, there are some points I need to clarify.

I initially did not want to buy an acoustic piano, because I was afraid of all the care it required (tuning, humidity, temperature, awkward family members, animal, etc.), but then I realised many of them apply for a digital piano anyway.

Tuning is simple. Humidity level can be easily monitored using a device. Family members and animal can be dealt with by having the piano in a room that isn't often visited.

But I have no idea how to prevent temperature from rising or dropping to critical level during Winter or Summer. I mean, I can have the piano in a room without windows and good isolation. But if the air itself is burning hot, there is nothing I can do to keep the piano room cool (beside having an air conditioner, but I cannot afford having an air conditioner just for the piano).

What are the actual dangers of having a room below 10°C or above 35°C for a piano? I am afraid of seeing my piano wither just because I can't keep the room below 30°C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the temperature occasionally goes below 10°C or above 35°C there should be no problem as long as you can avoid sudden changes of temperature. You should at all costs avoid having the piano exposed to direct sunlight. It makes sense to keep the piano in a room that is heated to at least 15° during the winter.

If the temperature changes a lot, the piano will need tuning more often.

A bigger problem is humidity. Pianos prefer the humidity to be between 40 and 60%. If it goes much above 80% the wood is liable to swell, and below 30% the wood can dry out. It's worth investing in a hygrometer. If you live in a desert climate you'll definitely need a humidifier during the summer, and if you live in a cold climate you might need a humidifier during the winter.

Comment: So basically if the temperature is at a constant 35°C and the humidity level is stable at 60%, it should be fine even if it's above the preferred temperature of 25°C?

Comment: As "constant", I mean for several days or even weeks if it's a really hot summer, without going below 30.

Comment: @Clockwork If you live in a desert where the temperature is 35° every day and 5° every night, that could be a problem. Constant 35° should be ok.

Comment: Many pianos are manufactured at the temperature & humidity of the geographical area in which they will be sold, then vac-packed until they reach there. I'm not sure how they deal with areas with very large temperature/humidity variations.

Comment: Seems like you need to direct this question at any potential piano manufacturers - it probably wouldn't be the first time they'd been asked.

Comment: I used to work for Yamaha - I've been to the piano factory in Hamamatsu, where I watched the assembly line, so this is word of mouth from the actual manufacturer. Additionally, the wood they're made from is seasoned in the geographical area the final piano will be sold & vac-packed to ship to the factory in Japan, so its entire life is spent at the correct temp/humidity.

Comment: Looking at their site, this is not mentioned - https://europe.yamaha.com/en/products/contents/musical_instrument_guide/piano/manufacturing/index.html - so maybe they now have sufficiently well-controlled environments that it is no longer necessary to season in the correct geolocation; nor do they mention the vac-wrap process… though I have seen it done, it was 25 years ago.

Comment: So I contacted the piano manufacturer of the brand I had chosen, and they pretty much said what PiedPiper did. They just added to avoid direct contact from the sun, the moon (why?), and a heater.